# Litres, height, surface area

Tags: algebra-precalculus

2 similar pitchers of different height. The smaller pitcher has a height of 3cm while the larger pitcher has a height of 20cm

A) the smaller pitcher can hold 0.054litres of water. Calculate the volume of water the larger pitcher can hold

B) the smaller pitcher cost $1.5 to paint its surface area. Calculate how much it costs to paint the surface area of the larger pitcher, assuming that the cost per unit area is the same

I have done (a) but I'm stuck at (b). I was wondering, can one say that the litres from (a) be the surface area for (b) ??? Or do I have to calculate and if so how do I calculate. This is the first time I have encounter with this question so I do not know the steps of doing it

Answer (score 2):

If two objects are "similar" (have the same shape and proportions), then if the ratio of the lengths of one side (or the heights or any corresponding measurement) is $ \ \frac{L_2}{L_1} \ $ , the ratio of their surface areas is

$$\frac{S_2}{S_1} \ = \ \left( \ \frac{L_2}{L_1} \ \right)^2 $$

and the ratio of their volumes is

$$\frac{V_2}{V_1} \ = \ \left( \ \frac{L_2}{L_1} \ \right)^3 \ . $$

Notice that the exponent corresponds to the dimension of the measurement quantity (surface areas are two-dimensional, volumes, three-dimensional).